# How to read data file with year and week number

Tags: r, time-series

My file has year number and week number, I'm wondering how I can read that into a ts accordingly (i.e. 52 week years)

ex:

```
Year,Week,Data
2011,1,500
2011,2,600
...
2013,52,700
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like following. Key is to parse the `Year Week` as `POSIXct` using format `%Y %U` format. But you also need to specify week starting day. Hence We parse `Year Week 1` using `%Y %U %u` format. Check `?strptime` for more details.

```
DF <- read.csv(text='Year,Week,Data
2011,1,500
2011,2,600
2013,52,700')

require(xts)

data.xts <- xts(DF$Data, as.POSIXct(paste0(DF$Year, " ", DF$Week, " 1"), format = "%Y %U %u"))

data.xts
##            [,1]
## 2011-01-03  500
## 2011-01-10  600
## 2013-12-30  700
```